# Invalid credentials message login Symfony 4.4

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, symfony4

I'm trying to login one user in Symfony 4.4 but I get this message "Invalid credentials". I don't know how to solve it. I saw some post in this platform I don't solve my problem with them.

security.yalm file

```
security:
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    users:
        entity:
            # the class of the entity that represents users
            class: 'App\Entity\User'
            property: 'email'
encoders:
    # use your user class name here
    App\Entity\User:
        # Use native password encoder
        # This value auto-selects the best possible hashing algorithm
        # (i.e. Sodium when available).
        algorithm: bcrypt    
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: lazy
        provider: users
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
        logout:
            path: logout
            # where to redirect after logout
            # target: app_any_route

        # activate different ways to authenticate
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
        # switch_user: true

# Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
# Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
access_control:
    # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

LoginFormAuthenticator.php

class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator
{
use TargetPathTrait;

```
public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'login';

private $entityManager;
private $urlGenerator;
private $csrfTokenManager;

public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator, CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager)
{
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
    $this->csrfTokenManager = $csrfTokenManager;
}

public function supports(Request $request)
{
    return self::LOGIN_ROUTE === $request->attributes->get('_route')
        && $request->isMethod('POST');
}

public function getCredentials(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = [
        'email' => $request->request->get('email'),
        'password' => $request->request->get('password'),
        'csrf_token' => $request->request->get('_csrf_token'),
    ];
    $request->getSession()->set(
        Security::LAST_USERNAME,
        $credentials['email']
    );

    return $credentials;
}

public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
{
    $token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token']);
    if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
        throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
    }

    $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['email' => $credentials['email']]);

    if (!$user) {
        // fail authentication with a custom error
        throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Email could not be found.');
    }

    return $user;
}

public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
{
    return "Logeado";
    // Check the user's password or other credentials and return true or false
    // If there are no credentials to check, you can just return true
    throw new \Exception('TODO: check the credentials inside '.__FILE__);
}

public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
{
    if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
        return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
    }

    // For example : return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('some_route'));
    throw new \Exception('TODO: provide a valid redirect inside '.__FILE__);
}

protected function getLoginUrl()
{
    return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
}
```

}

User Entity

```
class User implements UserInterface
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
private $isVerified = false;

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getUsername(): ?string 
{
    return $this->username;
}

public function setUsername(string $username): self
{
    $this->username = $username;

    return $this;
}

public function getPassword(): ?string
{
    return $this->password;
}

public function setPassword(string $password): self
{
    $this->password = $password;

    return $this;
}

public function getEmail(): ?string
{
    return $this->email;
}

public function setEmail(string $email): self
{
    $this->email = $email;

    return $this;
}

public function getRoles()
{
    // TODO: Implement getRoles() method.
}

public function getSalt()
{
    // TODO: Implement getSalt() method.
}

public function eraseCredentials()
{
    // TODO: Implement eraseCredentials() method.
}

public function isVerified(): bool
{
    return $this->isVerified;
}

public function setIsVerified(bool $isVerified): self
{
    $this->isVerified = $isVerified;

    return $this;
}
```

}

SecurityController.php

```
class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
/**
 * @Route("/login", name="login")
 */
public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
{
    // if ($this->getUser()) {
    //     return $this->redirectToRoute('target_path');
    // }

    // get the login error if there is one
    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', ['last_username' => $lastUsername, 'error' => $error]);
}

/**
 * @Route("/logout", name="logout")
 */
public function logout()
{
    throw new \LogicException('This method can be blank - it will be intercepted by the logout key on your firewall.');
}
```

Comment: There are many questions on this exact topic.  You said you looked at some but they didn't solve the issue.  Does not really help us much.  Your 'anonymous: lazy' is indeed very strange.  Since you are just learning I would suggest creating a new 4.4 project and then follow the security docs exactly until you get something that works.  After that you will probably have what you need to solve your particular issue.

Comment: I did that. I used the official docs and I used the command that it said to create the new proyect. It is the default setting that this command create. I only change providers config in this file

Comment: Does your security.yaml file have an encoders section?  I got bored, made a new 4.4 project, ran make:user and make:auth and it all worked out of the box.

Comment: By default it don't have but I update de post and now it have a encoder section. However, Invalid credentials messaget is yet. Can you update to github your proyect to looking for differencies between both?

Comment: Your posted Authenticator::checkCredientals method has 'return "Logeado";' I assume that was just for debugging?  Have it return true and see if that gets you anywhere differently.

Comment: that is default config I didn't write that. I'm goint to try that

Comment: Nothing changed

Comment: I can assure you that Logeado is not part of the default configuration.  You have quite a few other tweaks in there as well.  Check your project in github and provide a link.  Right now we are just going around in circles with me trying to guess what your actual code is.  Again, new project, make:user, make:auth and nothing else.

Comment: I really don't write that because I don't know what that code meaning.I'm foint to give you the the github link

Comment: This is the proyect https://github.com/CristinaEsteban97/ProyectoFinalDAW

Comment: You might want to check the link you posted.

Comment: Now it's ok, sorry

Comment: Did you see the problem?  I don't get to fix it

Comment: One of use is very confused.  Honestly not sure which.  You keep insisting that this is new code created fresh out of the box but then you post code with invalid LoginFormAuthenticator checkCredentials and onAuthenticationSuccess methods.  As a bonus, your presumably generated User entity has no roles?  I could try giving you specific fixes for each problem but I think we are just talking past each other.  On the plus side, your registration code seems to work.

Comment: ok, any problem. I will try to solve alone :(. Yes, the register area runs

Comment: I get to solve it but really I don't know why. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

if you set property to 'email'
in your user entity getusername must return the email you should change it

Comment: why? Because I have both methods(getUsername and get Email)

Comment: Yea authentication will always call getusername and that should return the email not username

Comment: how can I update it? Because I change it and I clear cache and it dont works

Comment: I need you to check something in my security.yaml I defined anonymous:true and lazy:true but you put it as anonymous: lazy that could be a problem

Comment: Setting the user provider property to email in security.yaml will cause getEmail to be used.  So you can pretty much ignore this answer as it is just plain wrong.

Comment: And what I can do to solve my problem please? I'm new in Symfony